# global option for gganimate renderer (no loop)

Tags: r, gganimate

I would like to stablish global options to a bunch of animations rendered using gganimate. The most important part is no-loop option but ...can not add to list of parameters this way. Every other option worked.

```
     options(gganimate.dev_args = list(width = 14,
                                        height = 7,
                                        units = 'in',
                                        res = 200,
                                        renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = F)))

Error in device(files[i], ...) : 
  unused argument (renderer = function (frames, fps)
```

Comment: This code works on my with: 1. install `png` and `gifski` packages; 2: load `gganimated` package first.

Comment: BE careful. After installing gifski and png all charts stopped to work. Error in args$renderer(frames_vars$frame_source, args$fps) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/user/Documents/Code/animations/packrat/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.5.1/gifski/R/gifski.rdb': No such file or directory
In addition: Warning message:
In args$renderer(frames_vars$frame_source, args$fps) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation